# "Mark" some part of a command as a prefix or postfix so it isn't affected by another command

Tags: macros

I'm in a rather unique situation. I'd like to "mark" parts of a command output as prefix or postfix. For example:

```
\newcommand{\L}[1]{L\postfix{_i}}
```

And then be able to do something like this:

```
\newcommand{\est}[1]{\prefixof{#1}\hat{\mainbodyof{#1}}\postfixof{#1}}
```

Ideally, this should work on normal text, e.g. `\est{\lambda}` should expand to `\hat{\lambda}`. Also, `\L` should expand to `L_i`, and `\est{\L}` should expand to `\hat{L}_i`.

I know this is possible with TeX (it being Turing complete and all), but I have no idea where to even start, or what tags to put in the question exactly other than `macros`.

It seems @DavidCarlisle's answer doesn't work in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\zzfix[3]{#1#2#3}%pre-main-post

\def\prefixof#1{\expandafter\zzpre#1\relax{#1}}
\def\postfixof#1{\expandafter\zzpost#1\relax{#1}}
\def\mainbodyof#1{\expandafter\zzmain#1\relax{#1}}


\def\zzpre#1{\ifx\zzfix#1\expandafter\oneoffive\else\expandafter\gobblepastrelax\fi}
\def\zzpost#1{\ifx\zzfix#1\expandafter\threeoffive\else\expandafter\gobblepastrelax\fi}
\def\zzmain#1{\ifx\zzfix#1\expandafter\twooffive\else\expandafter\afterrelax\fi}

\def\oneoffive#1#2#3\relax#4{#1}
\def\twooffive#1#2#3\relax#4{#2}
\def\threeoffive#1#2#3\relax#4{#3}
\def\afterrelax#1\relax#2{#2}
\def\gobblepastrelax#1\relax#2{}

\newcommand{\queueState}[1][]{\zzfix{}{\ell}{\ifstrempty{#1}{}{_{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\baseQuantity}[1]{\prefixof{#1}\bar{\mainbodyof{#1}}\postfixof{#1}}


\begin{document}
    But this does not work: $\baseQuantity{\queueState[1:N]}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Non-working example]

Maybe it's possible to make it work for this, too?

`\show\queueState` output:

```
> \queueState=macro:
->\@protected@testopt \queueState \\queueState {}.
```

Comment: How deeply nested do you want this to be?  E.g. do you want `\est{\est{\L}}` to give `\hat{\hat{L}}_i`?

Comment: I guess I could do define `est` itself with a prefix and postfix if I wanted to do that.

Comment: `\zzfix` has to be the first token in the expansion (so not nested), I don't see why you need the `\ifstrempty` test at all since you have defined it as an optional argument.  latex is already testing for it being there/not being there, no need to test again.

Comment: I needed it because I needed to put a subscript on `\ell` depending on whether or not the optional command was there.

However, I modified my example so `\zzfix` is the first token and it still doesn't work, unfortunately. See my edit. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\zzfix[3]{#1#2#3}%pre-main-post  



\renewcommand{\L}{\zzfix{}{L}{_i}}

\newcommand{\est}[1]{\prefixof{#1}\hat{\mainbodyof{#1}}\postfixof{#1}}

\def\prefixof#1{\expandafter\zzpre#1\relax{#1}}
\def\postfixof#1{\expandafter\zzpost#1\relax{#1}}
\def\mainbodyof#1{\expandafter\zzmain#1\relax{#1}}


\def\zzpre#1{\ifx\zzfix#1\expandafter\oneoffive\else\expandafter\gobblepastrelax\fi}
\def\zzpost#1{\ifx\zzfix#1\expandafter\threeoffive\else\expandafter\gobblepastrelax\fi}
\def\zzmain#1{\ifx\zzfix#1\expandafter\twooffive\else\expandafter\afterrelax\fi}

\def\oneoffive#1#2#3\relax#4{#1}
\def\twooffive#1#2#3\relax#4{#2}
\def\threeoffive#1#2#3\relax#4{#3}
\def\afterrelax#1\relax#2{#2}
\def\gobblepastrelax#1\relax#2{}



\begin{document}


Ideally, this should work on normal text, e.g. $\est{\lambda}$ should
expand to $\hat{\lambda}$. Also, $\L$ should expand to $L_i$, and $\est{\L}$
should expand to $\hat{L}_i$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you check out my edit? It seems your answer doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: It might not be possible to make it general (I don't know) but I can say that the input will contain exactly one (possibly nested) `zzfix`, or it can fail-over to rendering it normally.

Comment: Could you check my second edit? I changed it so `\zzfix` is the first token and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi it needs to be the first token in the expansion (doing anything else while supporting the use like `\lambda` where it is not used at all would be much harder) as you have an optional argument the command `\queueState` expands to `\protect\queueStatex`  and `\queueStatex` expands to `\@ifnextchar[...`  so `\zzfix` is only seen after multiple expansions and multiple internal `\def` while testing if the next character is `[`.

Comment: It seems you haven't seen my edit... I made `\zzfix` the first token and moved everything else inside it. In the definition for `\queueState`.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi yes I was explaining what your definition means. look at `\show \queueState` output in the log you will see that `\zzfix` is not there.

Comment: I was talking about my second edit. :-) I rewrote the definition for `\queueState` so `\zzfix` is the first token in its expansion.

Comment: Oh, I now understand, does it not work because it's inside \baseQuantity?

Comment: no as I wrote above `\zzfix` needs to be the first token in the expansion of `\queueState` and it is not.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I re-wrote it so it is. New definition: `\newcommand{\queueState}[1][]{\zzfix{}{\ell}{\ifstrempty{#1}{}{_{#1}}}}`

Comment: @HameerAbbasi  did you do as I suggest and test with `\show\queueState` what the definition of `\queueState` is after that command?

Comment: I added the output to my question. It seems it was an issue of the optional argument. Is there a way to handle optional/starred arguments? If not, I'll settle for defining different commands for everything.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi yes as I explained above the optional argument means the expansion is different:-) not easily, although as I said initially testing with ifstrempty here makes little sense anyway